# OpenCV 2.4.2 findContours throws error (with CV example prog)

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I got Ubuntu 12.04 32bit running in VMware. I installed OpenCV 2.4.2 after this (http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/).

When I try to run the example for findContours from CV-Page (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html), it compiles, but crashes on the "findContours" call.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (k == STD_VECTOR_MAT) in release, file /build/build   /opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1364
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1364: error: (-215) k == STD_VECTOR_MAT in function release
```

I don't know, what's the problem...

I run the code in Eclipse with. CDT Build Console says:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/FrameTest.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/FrameTest.d" -MT"src/FrameTest.d" -o "src/FrameTest.o" "../src/FrameTest.cpp"
../src/FrameTest.cpp:26:2: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
../src/FrameTest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/FrameTest.cpp:319:25: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
../src/FrameTest.cpp: In function ‘void thresh_callback(int, void*)’:
../src/FrameTest.cpp:345:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
Finished building: ../src/FrameTest.cpp

Building target: FrameTest
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/home/ubu/workspace/opencv -L/usr/share -L/usr/share/doc/libcv-dev -L/lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/home/ubu/OpenCV-2.4.2/include/opencv -L/home/ubu/OpenCV-2.4.2/include/opencv2 -o "FrameTest"  ./src/FrameTest.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lpthread -lopencv_imgproc
Finished building target: FrameTestenter code here
```

Someone got an idea? I got other code from an old project running with CV2.2 in Windows with VS2010 and it works... Where is the difference VStudio with Win vs. Eclipse and Ubuntu?

Thanks so far.

Comment: you said you installed  OpenCV 2.4.2  but in the error the library are located in opencv-2.3.1 or so please clarify this.

Comment: yes, there must be an issue with that. I want to uninstall and rebuild the newest version. Hope that works. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have two versions of OpenCV installed, and the linker tries to use a different one for linking than the one used to compile your code.

The simplest way is to remove all the other old OpenCV versions, and then a possible wrong library path will be more explicit. check all the settings PATH, linker flags and include folders to make sure you are using the same version through the include/complile/link settings

Comment: It always to use the latest version. Try the tutorials for opencv2.4, but make sure the paths for linker and include lib use the opencv2.4. and Accept the answer

Comment: Okay, upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, I want to delete all old OpenCV and compile 2.4.3.
What is the best way to uninstall CV completely to get a the new version?
Thanks so far!

Comment: It's funny how you copy pasted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377400/opencv-inputarray-outputarray instead of linking to it.