# Yellow detection program assertion failed

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, arm

I created a program to detect and track yellow color using c++ and opencv.
This program works normally on my PC with windows and ubuntu OS, but this program cannot run in my debian arm miniPC.

I am getting error: **opencv error: Assertion failed (k==STD_VECTOR_MAT) in getMat., file /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-armhf-d9JIli/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 918**

I tried to comment the code below and I found that one of the problem was on function inRange() but i have no idea what's wrong with it, since this program works on my PC.

I am using qtcreator 2.5.0 qt 4.8.2 and opencv 2.3.1-11

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//VARIABLE LIST///////////////////////////////////////
int cap_x_size=320;
int cap_y_size=240;
int posx,posy;

//matrix1
bool betulyellow1;
string yellow1="yellow";
string yellowind = "yellow";
int yellow1posx, yellow1posy;

//matrix2
bool betulyellow2;
string yellow2="yellow";
int yellow2posx, yellow2posy;

vector<vector<Point> > leftcontur;
vector<vector<Point> > rightcontur;
vector<vector<Point> >::const_iterator itc;

Moments momon;
double momon01,momon10,momonrea;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

Mat left(240, 320, CV_8UC3);
Mat right(240, 320, CV_8UC3);
Mat lefthsv(240, 320, CV_8UC3),righthsv(240, 320, CV_8UC3);
Mat LYellow(240, 320, CV_8UC3),RYellow(240, 320, CV_8UC3);

VideoCapture cap;
VideoCapture cap2;

cap.open(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cap_x_size);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, cap_y_size);

cap2.open(1);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cap_x_size);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, cap_y_size);

while(1)
{
    cap>>left;
    cap2>>right;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    cvtColor(left,lefthsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvtColor(right,righthsv,CV_BGR2HSV);

    inRange(lefthsv,Scalar(22,100,100), Scalar(38,255,255),LYellow);
    inRange(righthsv,Scalar(22,100,100), Scalar(38,255,255),RYellow);

    Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(3,3));
    Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(8,8));

    //left
    erode(LYellow,LYellow,erodeElement);
    dilate(LYellow,LYellow,dilateElement);

    //right
    erode(RYellow,RYellow,erodeElement);
    dilate(RYellow,RYellow,dilateElement);

    //left
    findContours(LYellow,leftcontur,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    drawContours(LYellow,leftcontur,-1,Scalar(255),1);

    //right
    findContours(RYellow,rightcontur,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    drawContours(RYellow,rightcontur,-1,Scalar(255),1);

    //left
    for(itc = leftcontur.begin(); itc<leftcontur.end(); itc++) 
    {
        momon = moments(Mat(*itc));
        momon10 = momon.m10;
        momon01 = momon.m01;
        momonrea= momon.m00; // momonrea is area
        posx = momon10/momonrea;
        posy = momon01/momonrea;
            circle(left,Point(posx,posy),2, Scalar(0,255,255),2);
            putText(left,yellow1,Point(posx,posy-20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
            putText(left,intToString(posx)+ " , " + intToString(posy),Point(posx,posy+20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
            if(yellow1 == yellowind)
            {
                betulyellow1 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                betulyellow1 = false;
            }
    }
    if(betulyellow1)
    {
        yellow1posx=posx;
        yellow1posy=posy;
        betulyellow1=false;
    }
    else
    {
        yellow1posx=0;
        yellow1posy=0;
    }


    //right
    for(itc = rightcontur.begin(); itc<rightcontur.end(); itc++) //brapa objek yang uda di konturin
    {
        momon = moments(Mat(*itc));
        momon10 = momon.m10;
        momon01 = momon.m01;
        momonrea= momon.m00; // momonrea is area
        posx = momon10/momonrea;
        posy = momon01/momonrea;
            circle(right,Point(posx,posy),2, Scalar(0,255,255),2);
            putText(right,yellow1,Point(posx,posy-20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
            putText(right,intToString(posx)+ " , " + intToString(posy),Point(posx,posy+20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
            if(yellow2 == yellowind)
            {
                betulyellow2 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                betulyellow2 = false;
            }
    }
    if(betulyellow2)
    {
        yellow2posx=posx;
        yellow2posy=posy;
        betulyellow2=false;
    }
    else
    {
        yellow2posx=0;
        yellow2posy=0;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    imshow("left",LYellow);
    imshow("right",RYellow);
    imshow("left ori",left);
    imshow("right ori",right);

    if(waitKey(10)==27)//press esc to exit
    {
        destroyAllWindows();
        break;
    }
   }

return a.exec();
}
```

How can i fix this?

Thank you for your help

EDIT: stack results:

```
level    Function        File                                         Line
0        ??              /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6           0
1        raise           /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6           0
2        abort           /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6           0
3        __gnu_cxx::_... /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6  0
4        ??              /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6  0
5        ??              /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6  0
```

Answer (score 0):

inRange() returns grayscale output. i.e. the pixels that are in range, or not. You should declare Lyellow and Ryellow as 1 channel Mat structs, like CV_8UC1.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I change the of declaration of LYellow and RYellow to Mat LYellow(240,320, CV_8UC1), but I still get the same error

Comment: can you debug through your code, inrange should have no problem right now. in fact it looks like a capture/highgui problem. can you also copy the stack output ? do you any other opencv version installed?

Comment: sorry but what is stack output? I don't have any other opencv version installed. If i comment the inRange() and contours, the program runs and the output will be the hsv output with the erode and dilate.

Comment: stack trace, the underlying method calls when the exception is thrown

Comment: is this the one? Assertion failed (k==STD_VECTOR_MAT) in getMat., file /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-armhf-d9JIli/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 918

Comment: no, it is an exception thrown, call stack is different, you need to give us the debugger results like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377400/opencv-inputarray-outputarray

Comment: I have add on edit. by the way, the error still exists even when the camera is not connected